# El método de mi clase no realiza la operación ¿A que se debe?

Tags: python, poo, idle

Estoy aprendiendo a programar, este programa es respecto a la Programación Orientada a Objetos. La idea es, que uno de los métodos muestra en pantalla la información sobre un empleado(nombre, número de empleado, salario por hora y sus horas laborales); mientras que el otro método calcula el salario de un día con la multiplicación de las horas laborales por el salario de cada hora. No entiendo porque, pero no me da el resultado de dicha operación.

Intente utilizar un **get** pero aun así no funcionó. Intenté cambiar varias cosas pero siempre me tira esta línea de código como resultado:

**<bound method Empleado.calcula_salario of <**main**.Empleado object at 0x02D69550>>**

Este sería mi código:

```
class Empleado():

    def __init__(self, nombre, numeroEmpleado, salario_hora, horas_laborales):

        self.nombre = nombre
        self.numeroEmpleado = numeroEmpleado
        self.salario_hora = salario_hora
        self.horas_laborales = horas_laborales

    def mostrar(self):
        print("Nombre:", self.nombre, "\nNumero de Empleado:", self.numeroEmpleado, "\nSalario por hora:", self.salario_hora, "\nHoras laborales:",
              self.horas_laborales)

    def calcula_salario(self):

        self.Horas = self.horas_laborales
        self.Salario = self.salario_hora
        self.TSalario = 0

        self.TSalario = self.Horas*self.Salario

        print("Salario por dia:", self.TSalario)
        

    
miEmpleado = Empleado("", "20030927", 8000, 8)
print(miEmpleado.mostrar())
print(miEmpleado.calcula_salario)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensajeq ue sale en ese print es porque no estás llamando a la función, así que te imprime la *información* de la función. Si hicieras esto correría bien:

```
print(miEmpleado.calcula_salario())
```

De cualquier forma, estás haciendo unas llamadas a print duplicadas. O bien devuelves strings en las funciones y usas el print desde fuera, o las propias funciones llaman a print (como lo tienes en este momento) y entonces tu código debería ser así:

```
miEmpleado = Empleado("", "20030927", 8000, 8)
miEmpleado.mostrar()
miEmpleado.calcula_salario()
```